# Is 15.0F in Java 0x4170 in Smali?

Tags: java, numbers, smali

I'm trying to edit a smali file in smali itself. I do however have the corresponding java file.

[image: comparing the code]

I'm trying to figure out why a `15.0F` in java is `0x4170` in smali? Isn't [0x4170 in decimal = 16752](http://www.google.com/search?q=0x4170+in+decimal)?

Code: [java](http://pastebin.com/CP2Ka1m0), [smali](http://pastebin.com/D769jfaQ)

Comment: Note: it is setting the high 16 bits so its actually 0x41700000

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353580/android-smali-question :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes. See http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html

`15.0f` = `0x41700000` as a 32-bit IEEE-754 floating point number. The value `0x4170` would seem to imply 16-bit floats, which wouldn't have enough precision to be useful.

For completeness, `15.0d` (64-bit float) is `0x402E000000000000`.

Comment: +1 and the high-16 bits is 0x4170.  By setting the top 16-bit to be 4170 it may be implying the low 16-bit is 0000 and thus a more compact form.  Imagine the 64-bit value could be set using the high-16 bits 402E, it would be much smaller.